# How to import a android project into android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I want to study the source code of [android-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/) .But when I download the source code and import this into android studio, the android studio pop up a dialog with a title"Import Gradle Project" and a blank to fill named Gradle home. Does any one know why this happens? And what to fill in Gradle home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code doesn't include the Gradle wrapper files, which it should; the Gradle wrapper is responsible for automatically downloading the correct version of Gradle so you don't have to go through this trouble. I would recommend that you copy the Gradle wrapper over from another project into this source tree and use it. In another project that you've created with the New Project wizard, copy these files to the root directory of the project:

- **gradlew**
- **gradlew.bat**
- **gradle**     (directory)

When you open up the project in Android Studio it's likely to complain about the version of the Android Gradle plugin and offer to fix it for you; let it do that. If you're running the latest version of Android Studio (0.4.6 as of this writing), it's fairly smart about getting the versions of Gradle and the plug-in right, but in older versions it could get a little confused and have to ask you multiple times.

NOTE: instead of copying the wrapper files over, you can instead install a compatible version of Gradle and put the installation directory in when it asks for Gradle home. That will work, but be aware that Android Studio is very finicky about what version of Gradle it's compatible with; usually it requires a specific version that isn't forward-compatible, so for example, if it wants 1.10, 1.11 won't work. As you upgrade Android Studio you'll have to upgrade Gradle as well and it will be a bit of a drag; if you use the wrapper it's easier to make that change.

By the time Android Studio hits 1.0, it will sort out the version issues with Gradle, and it won't be so picky about version numbers, but in the short term, it's a limitation.

Comment: "The source code doesn't include the Gradle wrapper files, which it should" -- no, it should not. Nobody should be getting their build tools from a random repo. Without decompiling and manually reviewing the JAR files that are part of the Gradle wrapper, we have no idea what is being downloaded and will be run on our development machines. It *might* be standard Gradle. It *might* be Gradle augmented with spyware. Only get your Gradle from a source that you trust.